# Growth condition for $\operatorname{Im}(z)/|cz+d|^2$ as $\operatorname{Im}(z)\rightarrow\infty$

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $\sigma^{-1}=\begin{pmatrix}a&b\\c&d \end{pmatrix}\in \operatorname{SL}_2{\mathbb{(R)}}$ with $c\neq0$.

The book says that $$\operatorname{Im}(\sigma^{-1}z)=\frac{\operatorname{Im}(z)}{|cz+d|^2}=O(1/\operatorname{Im}(z))$$ ($\operatorname{Im}(z)\rightarrow\infty$) uniformly on $|\operatorname{Re}
(z)|\leq h/2$.

My calculation is as follows:

$$\frac{\operatorname{Im}(z)^2}{|cz+d|^2}=\frac{\operatorname{Im}(z)^2}{c^2\operatorname{Im}(z)^2+(c\operatorname{Re}
(z)+d)^2}\leq\frac{1}{c^2}$$ for any $z\in\mathbb{H}$ so above arguments hold trivially.

I think there is something wrong because we did not use $\operatorname{Im}(z)\rightarrow\infty $ or $|\operatorname{Re}
(z)|\leq h/2$. (Actually I did not explain what $h$ is.)

Is there something wrong on my calculation?

Comment: The book probably wants to give the precise order of magnitude. If the real part was also growing, the big-$O$ estimate would be weak.

Comment: @Gary Thank you!